# Make an element draggable diagonally / on path

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've made elements draggable on a straight path and fixed to an axis before using jQuery UI, like so:

```
$('#element').draggable({
    axis:'y'
});
```

However, I'm wondering how to make an element draggable while following a certain path that is essentially a draggable line.

I basically have one style / position of the element in the beginning and another style / position of its end location and I want it to be draggable along the path between these two positions.

How can I do this with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: You might have to do this checking the x, y manually (by manually I mean write your own code) instead of using the methods jQuery UI provides.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Oh, okay. That seems inefficient though, checking the position for each pixel it moves. Is there a way I can tell it if it is along a line then let it be draggable on that line.

Comment: To be honest I don't think there will be much difference in performance since jQuery is doing the same thing to check if your coordinates are inside of a certain range. As far as I know this is the only to do it. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) might help you if you want to find every pixel in between.

Comment: I have come up with a new idea: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tpegbbk8gt

Comment: This doesn't require it to calculate every single pixel beforehand. It uses simple geometry to calculate the point on the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think jQuery provides that kind of functionality. However, you can do it in pure JavaScript, or use this plugin I made:

```
$.fn.dragBetween = function(eles) {
    var dragEle = this,
        md = false, offset, a, b, ab;
    eles[0] = $(eles[0])[0];
    eles[1] = $(eles[1])[0];
    dragEle.on("mousedown", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            mD = true;
            offset = new Vector(
                e.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
                e.clientY - this.offsetTop
            );
            a = new Vector(eles[0].offsetLeft, eles[0].offsetTop);
            b = new Vector(eles[1].offsetLeft, eles[1].offsetTop);
            ab = b.sub(a);
        }
    });
    $(window).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (!mD) return false;

        var cursor = new Vector(e.clientX, e.clientY).sub(offset).sub(a),
            mag = cursor.dot(ab) / ab.dot(ab),
            proj = ab.times(Math.max(0, Math.min(1, mag)));
        var final = proj.add(a);
        dragEle.css({
            top: final._arr[1],
            left: final._arr[0]
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }).mouseup(function() {
        mD = false;
    });
};
```

And this is the `Vector` class I wrote in a hurry:

```
function Vector(x, y) {
    this._arr = [x, y];
}
Vector.prototype.dot = function(v2) {
    var v1 = this;
    return v1._arr[0] * v2._arr[0] + v1._arr[1] * v2._arr[1];
}
Vector.prototype.add = function(v2) {
    var v1 = this;
    return new Vector(v1._arr[0] + v2._arr[0], v1._arr[1] + v2._arr[1]);
}
Vector.prototype.sub = function(v2) {
    var v1 = this;
    return new Vector(v1._arr[0] - v2._arr[0], v1._arr[1] - v2._arr[1]);
}
Vector.prototype.times = function(n) {
    var v = this;
    return new Vector(v._arr[0] * n, v._arr[1] * n);
}
```

To call it, simply do:

```
$("#drag").dragBetween(["#a", "#b"]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/0j6e60d8/
<s>For formula explanation, see: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tpegbbk8gt</s>

Comment: Imperfect, because it fails if `x1 == x2` or `y1 == y2`

Comment: @yckart - Dang. I thought I could get away with simple algebra, but it seems I might have to do it with vector projection.

Comment: @yckart Vector math saves the day once again: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/0j6e60d8/

Comment: Wow, great work! And also some kind of those fast [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/) vectors... :)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to use Derek's answer because you lose the other features jquery ui draggable provides like containment.

I found to make it drag diagonally, you can modify the css using the drag event like this:

```
$(".leftTopCircle").draggable({ axis:"x", containment: ".topLeft", scroll: false });
$(".leftTopCircle").on( "drag", function(event, ui){
    $(this).css("top", ui.position.left+"px");
});
```

Comment: Hello Bruce, can you provide the html or maybe a fiddle to show how your code could work? Need that, too. Thanks!